# How to stop button events from firing

Tags: vb.net, button

I have a problem with my `btnNext`.

I have `btnNext` and I want to limit it at its 9thclick.

After 9 clicks the button should become disabled. How do I do it?

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnnext.Click
  If btnnext.Text = "Submit" Then
    calculate()
    btnnext.Text = "Next>"
  ElseIf btnnext.Text = "Next>" Then
    CurrentRow += 5
    cat += 5
    showdata()
    updatelbl()
    clear_radio()
    ' calculate_case(1)
    ' calculate_case(2)
    ' calculate_case(3)
    ' calculate_case(4)
    btnnext.Text = "Submit"
    If CurrentRow & cat = ds.Tables("evaluation").Rows.Count >= 20 Then
      MsgBox("Last Questions is Reached!!!")
    End If
    If btnnext.Text = "Management of Learning" Then
      btnnext.Text = "Finish"
      If btnnext.Text = "Finish" Then
        CurrentRow = 35
        cat = 35
        MsgBox("Comment")
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 9 clicks per application instance, user or server?

Comment: You need to do that manually in code, count how many times it was clicked then just disable it. Your count should consider the context as pointed out by Neolisk

Comment: Keep in mind it is not a good idea to base certain behavior conditions on the `Text` value of a control. Think about what would happen if you wanted to change what the button said or port the code to support another language.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Private btnCount As Integer
 Private Sub Button3_Click(...)...
  btnCount += 1
  If btnCount = 9 Then Button3.Enabled = False
  'remainder of code here...
```

Comment: You can also stash the count in the .Tag property, that way you can increment/decrement the count from anywhere (as with the above code.) I'd use > 8 or =>9. Button3.Enabled = NOT (Button3.Tag >8)

Comment: Also if you are running intense code it may take a while for the .Enable change to take place - rapid clicks may get through.

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static ctClicks As Integer = 0
    ctClicks += 1
    If ctClicks = 9 Then Button1.Enabled = False
    'other code
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: A static local? Never saw that one actually used before.